# JQUERY + Check Variable to ensure it only contains alpha or numeric

Tags: php, jquery, preg-match

I use this in PHP to ensure a variable contains only alpha or numeric:

```
if(preg_match('/\W/', $username)) {
    $loginerror[]=$siteLanguage->usernameinvalidchars;
};
```

How can I do the same check in JQUERY?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **you do not need jQuery for this** - raw JavaScript is enough. More specifically: `test()` method of `RegExp` object is enough ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)).

Second, you can do this similarly to the following:

```
if (/\W/.test(username)){
    // non-alphanumeric character found in username
    loginerror.push(siteLanguage.usernameinvalidchars);
}
```

where `str` is your string and `/\W/.test(username)` returns `true` if there is non-alphanumeric character within `username` (`false` otherwise). See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MnfSP/2/) for proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla JS.
Try this:

```
if (/\W/.test(<THE-TEST-VALUE>)) {
 //Do something..
}
```